# How do I uncheck the other selected list items that was previously select after I click on "Select All"?

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have these codes that allow me to disable all other checkboxes when I check on "Select All" however if I previously did check on other checkboxes before checking on "Select All", previously checked boxes does not get removed but only disabled with the boxes still checked. so how can I uncheck the other selected list items that was previously select after I click on "Select All"?

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="Checkboxlist1" runat="server" Height="80px" Width="500px" AppendDataBoundItems="True" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Select All" Value="Select All"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:CheckBoxList> 


  $(function () {
    $("#Checkboxlist :checkbox").change(function () {
        $("#Checkboxlist  :checkbox").click(function () {
            var ischecked = $(this).is(":checked");
            var val = $(this).val();
            //alert(val);
            if (val == "Select All") {
                if (ischecked) {                    
                    $("#Checkboxlist  :checkbox").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
                    $(this).attr('checked', true)
                    return;
                } else {                 
                    $("#Checkboxlist  :checkbox").removeAttr('disabled');
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: You can use Jquery `not()` function and pass `this` as parameter e.g. `$("#Checkboxlist1:checkbox").not(this).removeAttr("disabled");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `else`, before `return` simply remove the disabled from `Select All`:

```
$(this).removeAttr("disabled");
```

**OR**

just edit your `selector` for not having the `checkbox` whose value is `Select All`:

```
$("#Checkboxlist1:checkbox[value='Select All']")
```

**Code:**

```
if (val == "Select All") {
    //if Select All is checked, disable all other checkboxes and uncheck them as well
    if (ischecked) {
        $("#Checkboxlist1:checkbox").attr("disabled", "disabled"); //disable all checkboxes
        $("#Checkboxlist1:checkbox").prop('checked', false);  //uncheck all checkboxes          
        $(this).prop('checked', true);  //check the "Select All" checkbox       
        return;
    }
    //enable all other checkboxes and uncheck them too
    else {
        $("#Checkboxlist1:checkbox").removeAttr("disabled"); //enable all checkboxes
        $("#Checkboxlist1:checkbox").prop('checked', false); //uncheck all checkboxes          
        $(this).prop('checked', false);  //uncheck the "Select All" checkbox
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but there seems to be another problem which is when I check "Select All" it enables the other check list items and when I uncheck it disables the other list items which should not happen this way but in another when I check "Select All" it should disable the rest of the checkboxes and when I Uncheck it should enable the rest of the list items. please advice

Comment: Actually your code logic is reversed, you just have to put the code of `if` block into the `else` block, and `else` block code into the `if` block.

Comment: Hi I did try but when I do so after I check It does not show the tick any more and the checking does not work after the first one

Comment: Hi I have updated my code to the newest but I do realise there are some errors to fixed. Now when I select all it works that it disables the rest however when I checked a few of other list items and checked on "select All", it disables the rest but it does not uncheck the other list items. how can I at the same time disable and uncheck the other list items when checking "Select All"?

Comment: You are already doing this in `else` block, here it is `$("#Checkboxlist1:checkbox").attr('checked', false);`. Check the updated answer as well.

Comment: Hi your If statement is $(this).removeAttr('disabled'); thus once it disabled we can enable it again. However the problem now is when I click on select all again it does not check select all (missing the tick)

Comment: I missed that part, fixed it now.

Comment: Hi your codes still doesn't work. can you edit (to uncheck other previously checked items when "Select All" is checked) on my updated codes above? Thanks a lot:) I actually tried adding $("#Checkboxlist1 :checkbox").attr('checked', false); to my if statement in the updated codes posted above but it give me error (when I click on select all it does not check the checkbox) after adding the $("#Checkboxlist1 :checkbox").attr('checked', false);

Comment: Hi Shaharyar, I managed to solve the problem already thanks for your help. I will need to use .prop instead of attr